# Application throws exception without debugger attached

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

I've got a kind of curious problem here, and to be quite honest I have no idea what's causing it.  For whatever reason, when I debug my application from Qt Creator my application runs just fine without any exceptions, but when I only **run** the application, I get a write access violation exception (as follows)

> (1f68.1ea8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
>
> Exception at 0x77da2073, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x0 in ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapFree
>
> First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
>
> This exception may be expected and handled.
>
> eax=00720065 ebx=82130074 ecx=006f007f edx=0000006f esi=01fa5fb6 edi=82130000   eip=77da2073 esp=0012cc70 ebp=0012cca4 iopl=0 nv up ei pl nz na po nc   cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010202
>
> ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapFree+0xc5:
>            77da2073 8930            mov     dword ptr [eax],esi ds:0023:00720065=????????
>
> Exception at 0x77da2073, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at:
>   0x1, flags=0x0
>
> NOTE: INFERIOR SPONTANEOUS STOP
>
> State changed from InferiorRunOk(11) to InferiorStopOk(14).

When I comment out the line it breaks at (after running, then manually attaching the debugger) it just seems to bring me to a different line for the same issue.  The tool chain I'm using is MSVCC, with the additional flags:

> QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Zi
>
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Zi -g
>
> QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /DEBUG /OPT:REF

To recount, here's what I've tried:

- Debugging with debug configuration - *ok*
- Running with debug configuration - *ok*
- Debugging with release configuration - *ok*
- Running with release configuration - *exception*

Answer (score 1):

Are you double freeing something? A quick search brings up [this article about double freeing](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2007/08/19/crash-dump-analysis-patterns-part-23a/).

I'm not sure what the MSVCC equivalent might be (the article mentions a tool called `gflags.exe`), but under Linux with GCC you can use a program called Valgrind with the memcheck tool to find this sort of problem.

Comment: It doesn't appear so.  It does break on a "delete[]" line but commenting that out doesn't help much.  Here's the code that it breaks on: http://pastebin.com/JMWyJ7Wy.  In the "ReadBytes" function (or functions called within), there's no delete or free statement anywhere.

Comment: Okay, now I've removed dynamically allocated arrays and I'm still getting a different exception each time.  I suppose a better question here would be "Why am I getting different behavior when debugging than I am when running the application, or running the application then attaching the debugger?"

Comment: See this article on [First and second chance exception handling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675), the debugger will break on a first chance, your program will crash on a second chance if the first isn't handled. As you are seeing different behaviour, the exception may be being handled, but then another different exception may be thrown due to the underlying problem.

Comment: If it is in fact a first chance exception, wouldn't it print something in the debugger window?